# Having an odd issue with SQLAlchemy and joins

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I save email addresses in two tables: userid and domain. The model looks something like this:

```
class Email():
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    parent_id = Column(Unicode, ForeignKey('domain.id'))
    parent = relationship('Domain')
    userid = Column(Unicode)

class Domain():
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    host = Column(Unicode)
```

I suddenly started having issues with joins. When I do the following, I always get None:

```
def get_email(email):
    fragments = email.lower().split(u'@')
    return DBSession().query(Email).filter(Email.userid == fragments[0]).join(Domain, Domain.id == Email.parent_id).filter(Domain.host == fragments[1]).first()
```

But if I separate this join into two queries, I retrieve the correct object:

```
def get_email(email):
    fragments = email.lower().split(u'@')
    session = DBSession()
    thehost = session.query(Domain).filter(Domain.host == fragments[1]).first()
    return session.query(Email).filter(Email.userid == fragments[0]).filter(Email.parent_id == thehost.id).first()
```

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong, or how I should go about troubleshooting? I spent the last 30 minutes to no avail... Thanks!

Comment: Does `Domain` class actually have `id` attribute? Did you forget to show it in your example?

Unrelated suggestion, I wouldn't use `local` as a variable name, since it clashes with a built in function `local()`.

Comment: yes. yeah, i just ended up using fragments instead of naming each fragment since i thought the word local was an issue, but that didn't help.

Comment: Why `Email.parent_id` is of type `Unicode`, while `Domain.id` is `Integer`? BTW, you can omit type for `ForeignKey` columns to let SQLAlchemy infer it.

Comment: Enable **SQL** statement logging by setting **echo=True**, and compare (add to the question) the resulting **SQL** statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the problem. Had to do with inheritance and aliasing. Lesson: If joining two objects inherited from the same object, alias at least one of the objects!